# Linq Query using Case statement and concatenate special character

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to convert the below SQL query into linq query but am unable to do it. i can you please help how to usethis type of case statement by doing join and concatenation a special character like '*' if record exists in another table. Please help me how to do this.

```
Select Distinct A.MyID, Title + case when D.MyID is not null then ' *' else '' end  as Title , MagTitle 
FROM [MasterTitles] A left outer join TitleDetails D on A.[MyID] = D.[MyID]
WHERE [PropertyID] is not null 
ORDER BY [Title]
```

Is there any better option. I have tried but am not able to figure out how to do this type of LINQ query. Someone please guide me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
        var result = database.MasterTitles.Where(m => m.PropertyID != null)
            .Join(database.TitleDetails, m => m.MyID, t => t.MyID, (m, t) => new { MyID = m.MyID, Title = m.Title + (t.MyID == null ? "" : "*" ), MagTitle = m.MagTitle })
            .OrderBy(m => m.Title)
            .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the query a little:

```
var result = from x in context.MasterTitles
             where x.PropertyID != null
             orderby x.Title
             select new { x.MyID, Title = x.TitleDetails.Any() ? x.Title + " *" : x.Title };
```

I've changed the `left join` to a `EXISTS()` (the `.Any()`). In this way I don't need the `Distinct()`

Comment: @HenkHolterman With different column names, on different table names, on EF 6.1.3 yes :-)

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is translated to `CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM ... WHERE ... (the join conditions) ) THEN [Extent1].[Title] + N' *' ELSE [Extent1].[Title] END ` I will say I would have written it in exactly the same way (minus the `N` before the `' *'`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this, not sure if LINQ can generate script for `?:`, if not just use `AsEnumerable` and another `select` before it

```
(from a in dc.MasterTitles
join d in dc.TitleDetails on a.MyId equals d.MyId into adJoin
from ad in adJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
order by a.Title
selec {a.MyId, Title = a.Title + (ad != null ? "*" : ""), a.MagTitle })
.Distinct()
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track but better make the AsEnumerable part of the answer. It's the core issue.